# Recommended minimum age to play Puppy Day?

Tags: kids, puppy-day

I read the rules for Puppy Day a while back, but I've started thinking about introducing it to some of my nieces and nephews who are between 5 and 7. The rules (which you can download for free [here](https://besw.itch.io/puppy-day) ) don't give any recommendations, so I'm either looking for commentary from the developer [BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw), or advice from people who have played the game with kids around those ages?

Comment: Are you interested in a recommended minimum age or whether the system is age-appropriate for your family members?

Comment: @akixkisu I'm struggling to see a difference, but I'm going to stick with my wording of "recommended minimum age".

Answer (score 1):

### I'd say 5+

The Game features turn-taking. But it's not as simple as round-robin turn-taking like Candyland, which is labeled 3+.

It also features sharing creative ideas about what an enclosure for an animal might look like, and acknowledgement of those ideas by others. The ideas ought to be coherent enough for other players to understand how they can interact with them. After age 5, kids usually have a bit of experience in cooperative imagination play.

The instructions don't have any concrete examples of game play, which is a mixed blessing since you can make up your own example that your kids might respond to. I know my kid would want to hear an example about a monkey named Bobo, from his favorite storybook.

Emphasizing these aspects of play, it ought to be enjoyable for kids 5+.